# Proving the Existence of the "Bureaucrat Term" in the Lambda Calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

From pg. 35 of *Lambda Calculus and Combinators An Introduction*:

> **Corollary 3.3.1** in $\lambda$ and $CL$: for every $Z$ and $n \ge 0$, the equation
>
> $$ xy_1 \ldots y_n = Z $$
>
> can be solved for $x$. That is, there is a term $X$ such that
>
> $$ Xy_1 \ldots y_n =_{\beta, w} [X/x]Z. $$
>
> *Proof:* Choose $X \equiv \mathsf{Y} (\lambda x y_1 \ldots y_n.Z)$.

**Note:** In the book, we assume that $\mathsf{Y} \equiv (\lambda ux. xuux)(\lambda ux. xuux)$. Further, for ease of notation, we can let $V \equiv (\lambda x y_1 \ldots y_n.Z)$.

As can be seen from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101598/trouble-replicating-proof-of-a-lambda-calculus-fixed-point-theorem-corollary), I am having trouble replicating the proof of this corollary on its own. That being said, even assuming it is true and that I understood why, I am having trouble understanding one of its consequences. In particular, the author later asserts that

> [This corollary] provides the world with ... a bureaucrat $X_2$ which
>   eternally permutes its arguments with no other effect,
>
> $$ X_2 y z =_{\beta, w} X_2 z y $$

But why is this?

Attempting to use the Corollary, we can set $z = x$ and $Z = X_2 y z$ and observe that it is true that

$$
Xy_1 \ldots y_n =_{\beta, w} [X/x] X_2 yx
$$

for some $X$.